# S3::Error::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, amazon-s3

Im getting this error when I try and make an object.  Here is my routine:

```
service = S3::Service.new(
    :access_key_id     => S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    :secret_access_key => S3_SECRET
  )
puts "connection established with s3"

puts "finding bucket"
bucket = service.buckets.find("test")
puts "building object"
object = bucket.objects.build("json_export/venues.txt")
puts "saving object"
object.save
```

It breaks after I see "saving object" so i'm assuming it's having trouble with object.save

It's a european bucket

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which library are you using.

I made a quick search and I guess you are using [S3](http://jah.pl/projects/s3.html).
Looking at the example in the homepage, you forgot to assign the `content =` to the object.

Also, have a look at the [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) project.

Comment: this didn't seem to help

Comment: If it didn't help, than why is the answer marked as correct?

Comment: accepting an answer that doesn't help is weird. And of course he was talking about S3 by just looking at the title.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while attempting to upload a file with special characters in the file name. Such as ñ, á, é...

Comment: Did you manage to get around this special character issue? I have the same problem.